# find if a page is rotated landscape when parsing pdf document using PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm trying to determine if the text on a pdf page flows vertically (bottom to top) instead of horizontally (left to right). So I attempted the answer on [How to find pdf is portrait or landscape using PDFBOX Library in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38919551/how-to-find-pdf-is-portrait-or-landscape-using-pdfbox-library-in-java#). I'm using pdfbox 2.0.3 and here's what my code looks like:

```
public PDFTextStripperChildClass() throws IOException {
    super();
    setSortByPosition(false);
    setShouldSeparateByBeads(true);
    setPageStart("");
    setPageEnd("");
    setParagraphEnd("");
    setParagraphStart("");
    setArticleStart("");
    setArticleEnd("");
    setLineSeparator("\n");

    isParsingOngoing = false;
}


@Override
protected void writeString(String txt, List<TextPosition> tp) {

    ...

    PDPage pdp = this.getCurrentPage();
    PDRectangle pdr = pdp.getMediaBox();
    boolean isLandscape = pdr.getWidth() > pdr.getHeight();
    int rotation = pdp.getRotation();

    if (isLandscape || rotation == 90 || rotation == 270) {
        System.out.println("landscape or rotated");
    }

    ...
}
```

Though when I ran it through a document with rotated landscape pages, nothing gets printed. Did I not bootstrap the PDFTextStripper correctly?

Comment: this is the file in question that I attempted to parse: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B54BrbCOErFMajR3NUhRYjZHZHc
the original file is 300 pages long so I trimmed the file. The first page is rotated landscape

Comment: The first page isn't rotated (rotation = 360, LOL), but the content stream has a rotated matrices at several places. To see this, use the PrintTextLocations example, and add `text.getTextMatrix()` to the output. To get the rotation, you'll need to convert this to an affinetransform with `.createAffineTransform()`, and then google "affinetransform get rotation" or remember your school math.

Comment: It seems inconsistent. `Math.acos(at.getScaleX() % Math.PI)` evaluates to NaN for some characters. Do all text in pdf comes with TextMatrix or do they only get it after some sort of transformation?

Comment: getTextMatrix() is always there. Prove me wrong :-)